# Can you change what time is "early" in iOS 8?

Tags: iphone, calendar, ios, notification-area

In the Notification Center of iOS 8 (and 7), you can see summaries for today and for tomorrow as well as today's schedule.

1. In the tomorrow section iOS sometimes states that my day starts early. Is it possible to change when my day need to start in order for it to be "early"? Now, it seems to think that pretty much all my days start early, which makes it a rather less useful feature.
2. I believe this is a bug more than anything customisable, but is it possible to change when iOS thinks that your day starts? This morning, at 05.30 am (GMT+1), the schedule section still showed yesterday's events (even though the today and tomorrow sections were on track with today).